# Top non-zero Betti number of connected manifold of finite type.

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, betti-numbers

The Top non-zero Betti number of a closed oriented manifold is one. is it true for the general manifold or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't true in general.  For example, take the nonorientable surface $(\mathbb{RP}^2)^{\# n}$ for $n>2$.  The only nontrivial reduced homology group is $\tilde{H}_1=\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ which doesn't have rank $1$.